# Nuxt3 AWS-Amplify Error: 'request' is not exported by __vite-browser-external,

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, aws-amplify

I am using **AWS-amplify** in my **Nuxt3** for user authentication. The AWS-amplify uses @aws-sdk built-in and this is producing an error once I try to run build command.

Once this code is added to my plugin:

```js
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure(config);
```

I try to build my project: `npm run generate` and getting the following error

**'request' is not exported by __vite-browser-external, imported by node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-imds/dist/es/remoteProvider/httpRequest.js**

I saw on GitHub for @aws-sdk this is a common error with vite.

Any suggestions or workaround for **Nuxt**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my issue by pasting the following code inside the `vite` object of the **nuxt.config.ts**.

```js
vite: {
    define: {
      "process.env.DEBUG": false,
      "window.global": {},
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        "./runtimeConfig": "./runtimeConfig.browser", //fix production build
      },
    },
  },
```